# Reading pdf metadata using php zend framework. Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, metadata, zend-pdf

I need to read pdf metadata before uploading to server. I couldn't find any php classes written anywhere for this. and interestingly there is a `pdf_set_info()` function but no `pdf_get_info()`

Now I'm trying to achieve this using Zend stand alone pdf parser,
Here is my code

```
<?php
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array('path/to/Zend/library',get_include_path(),)));
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$pdf = new Zend_Pdf("my_file.pdf");

?>
```

And that trows an exception 'File is not a PDF.'

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'File is not a PDF.'
in Zend/library/Zend/Pdf/Parser.php:396 Stack trace: #0 Zend/library/Zend/Pdf.php(318):
Zend_Pdf_Parser->__construct('my_file.pdf', Object(Zend_Pdf_ElementFactory_Proxy), false)
#1 Zend/zend.php(15): Zend_Pdf->__construct('my_file.pdf') #2 {main} thrown in Zend/library/Zend/Pdf/Parser.php on line 396
```

My pdf is not copyrighted or locked and it's `here http://69.49.225.82/pdf/my_file.pdf`

I tried this with zend [ZendFramework-1.12.0-minimal.tar.gz](http://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.12.0/ZendFramework-1.12.0-minimal.tar.gz)

Comment: I think this is a bug in Zend_pdf , you should report it.

Comment: Thanks nelson. Is there any suggestions? Regarding version? or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: what is your PHP version? you can look it up with phpinfo(); function.

Comment: Hello any suggestion on this? anybody?
Is it possible to user Zendframework 2 as a stand alone pdf parser? Any one guide me please. Any JavaScript/Client side solution for this?. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then you should try with a more up to date version of Zendframework, like ZendFramework-minimal-2.0.0.zip , because there have been several improvements to the string parser used by Zend_PDF (like these http://tinyurl.com/8otoa8u ).

Comment: Just tested with latest copy of ZF2 from github - same problem I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: So Nelson was correct. This is a Bug. Thanks Nelson & JamesG. by the way I could see my question edited by "Jeroen Moons". but still it looks same as original. what does does mean plz?